# Foreman errors out when provisioning using an ms-dhcp/dns smart proxy

Tags: dhcp, puppet, foreman

Im running foreman, with smart-proxy on a win2k12 r2 box running ad/dhcp/dns.

When i try to provision smart proxy dumps this to the logs:

```
Changed the current scope context to 192.168.20.0 scope.

The specified option does not exist.

E, [2014-09-11T19:31:03.050843 #6068] ERROR -- : Unknown error while processing ''
E, [2014-09-11T19:34:20.342416 #6068] ERROR -- : Netsh failed:


Changed the current scope context to 192.168.20.0 scope.

The specified option does not exist.

E, [2014-09-11T19:34:20.342416 #6068] ERROR -- : Unknown error while processing ''
```

foreman web interface says

```
Create DHCP Settings for testbox2.devita.co task failed with the following error: ERF12-6899     [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: Unable to set DHCP entry ([RestClient::BadRequest]: 400 Bad Request) for proxy https://win1.devita.co:8443/dhcp
```

smart-proxy stdout looks like this:

```
92.168.20.105 - - [11/Sep/2014 19:30:44] "GET /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from
192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23 1.4821
oreman.devita.co - - [11/Sep/2014:19:30:42 US Mountain Standard Time] "GET /dhc
/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23
 -> /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200
92.168.20.105 - - [11/Sep/2014 19:31:03] "POST /dhcp/192.168.20.0 HTTP/1.1" 400
33 1.0671
oreman.devita.co - - [11/Sep/2014:19:31:01 US Mountain Standard Time] "POST /dh
p/192.168.20.0 HTTP/1.1" 400 33
 -> /dhcp/192.168.20.0
he system cannot find the path specified.
92.168.20.105 - - [11/Sep/2014 19:32:33] "GET /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from
192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23 1.4941
oreman.devita.co - - [11/Sep/2014:19:32:32 US Mountain Standard Time] "GET /dhc
/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23
 -> /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200
he system cannot find the path specified.
92.168.20.105 - - [11/Sep/2014 19:34:00] "GET /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from
192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23 1.5431
oreman.devita.co - - [11/Sep/2014:19:33:59 US Mountain Standard Time] "GET /dhc
/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200 HTTP/1.1" 200 23
 -> /dhcp/192.168.20.0/unused_ip?from=192.168.20.100&to=192.168.20.200
92.168.20.105 - - [11/Sep/2014 19:34:20] "POST /dhcp/192.168.20.0 HTTP/1.1" 400
33 0.9841
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [bug #5995](http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/5995), which seems to be that we added a DHCP option that some/all(?) Active Directory servers seem to refuse.  I'd love to know more about it before we just revert it, any thoughts appreciated.

To fix it, you'll need to edit the smart proxy code and revert [the change](https://github.com/theforeman/smart-proxy/commit/296617a) that introduced the problem.

On Foreman 1.4 or 1.5, edit `/usr/share/foreman-proxy/lib/proxy/dhcp.rb` and comment out the code => 60 line:

```
# :PXEClient             => {:code => 60, :kind => "String"    }, # Needs to be empty for foreman to function
```

If you're on Foreman 1.6 the same line is now in `/usr/share/foreman-proxy/modules/dhcp/dhcp.rb`.